# Automatic redirect and error after sending a payment

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I sent a payment, then I was asked to login with buyer user, when the screen to select paypal balance option is displayed, an automatic redirection occurrs, then it tries to create a session but instead an error page is displayed and cannot complete the payment.
The attached image doesn't stay to show the options to pay, instead it redirects automatically without choosing paypal balance.
Is it a problem with paypal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Business and Personal account in the PayPal Sandbox.  Test with those. If you still have problems, post details about your payment flow.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I created both accounts then I tested the payment again, the form was loaded without redirecting, so I could process the payment successfully.